# In google sheets how do I make a list of names based on other multiple other columns data?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, count, google-query-language

For this example I've got a list of names with a variety of categories they can belong to.

I'd like to generate a sublist of names based on which category they're in which would appear in the cell the formula's in, using the cells below for additional names.

[image: Picture of the problem]

E.g. (poorly laid out text version because my org won't let me share publicly)

Name.....| Cat 1 | Cat 2 | Cat 3

Fred.....|...1...|.......|...1

Geoff....|.......|...1...|

Gertrude.|...1...|...1...|...1

Abigail..|.......|.......|...1

Comment: Managed to fix it myself with =IFERROR(QUERY(A2:D, "select A where (B=1)",0),)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in F2:

```
=FILTER(A2:A; FILTER(B2:D, B1:D1=F1)=1)
```

Comment: I think `=FILTER(A2:A, FILTER(B2:D, B1:D1=F1))` this should also work without last comparison with 1.